# Bloom Filters - is the blockchain filtered block by block?

Tags: logs, bloom-filter

I understand that bloom filters are used to quickly scan for log topics and corresponding contract addresses. I also understand that an 2048-bit bloom filter is stored in the block header.

**Question**: If I have a filter looking for a specific log topic value from block 0 to the latest block: how does the node search for this? Will it iterate over the bloom filters block by block starting by block 0? Or, is there a hierarchy of bloom filters (mipmaps?) so that multiple blocks can be filtered at once? **Bonus** for pointing to geth code location where this is implemented.

Comment: I did take a look and the code is at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/release/1.8/core/bloombits for the data structure and algorithms, and the start point is at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/release/1.8/eth/filters/filter.go#L119. I did not finish researching, but bloom bits appear to be stored in the database in compressed form, and the search seems to be lineal (blocks? sections??). I'll this here is someone want to continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got an answer to this.

The bloom filters are checked block by block. So if you call `eth_getLogs`  with `from:0` every header is checked.

[Code location in the geth code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e862cbff95ef76daf49779cff94aecaa54538aa4/eth/filters/filter.go#L218).

See also [this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/22529#issuecomment-804988407).